# Azure Mobile Services and Universal Apps SQLite Synchronization

Tags: sqlite, azure-mobile-services, win-universal-app

I have a normal Universal App, nothing fancy, really simple.

There is a SQLite database that weights more than 200KB (could be even 20MB, keep that in mind) and I want to share this database between Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 devices.

I guess that roaming data isn't enough, am I right?

So, I googled and find Azure Mobile Services and it's really sweet but the examples that are provided are too simply and I don't know how to extend it.

My database has 7 tables and some of them are connected by foreign key. Here is example one of my class (database is based on it).

```
public class Meeting : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
        public Meeting() { }

        private int _id;
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        private int _adressId;
        public int AdressId { get; set; }

        private Adress _adress;
        [Ignore]
        public Adress Adress { get; set; }
}
```

Then it is method

```
private async Task InitLocalStoreAsync()
{
    if (!App.MobileService.SyncContext.IsInitialized)
    {
        var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore("MyDatabase.db");
        store.DefineTable<Adress>();
        store.DefineTable<Contractor>();
        store.DefineTable<Item>();
        store.DefineTable<ItemGroup>();
        store.DefineTable<Meeting>();
        store.DefineTable<Note>();
        store.DefineTable<Order>();

        await App.MobileService.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store);
    }
}
```

and I get exception "Error getting value from 'Adress' on 'Projekt.DataModel.Meeting'."

**The thing is: It is really hard to work with this. Isn't there a simplier solution? I don't need at this moment nothing but synchronization of my database. Please remember that I have a tables that are connected by foreign key. Maybe I skip some worthy example or tutorial?**

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that this database would be too big for roaming settings. You should be able to get Azure Mobile Services working for your scenario.

One way to manage the relationships, especially if they are 1-to-many and not many-to-many, is to create database views in the backend that join the tables. Then you just sync against them. See my messages on this forum thread that describes how this would work: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/4c056373-d5cf-4ca6-9f00-f152d2b01372/best-practice-for-syncing-related-tables-in-offline-mode?forum=azuremobile

You might also be interested in a solution accelerator we have built, that shows how you would connect everything in a real app: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Field-Engineer-501df99d

If you have more questions, feel free to post in our forums that the product team monitors regularly: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/home?forum=azuremobile